# trobule with wordpress wishlist membership plugin

Tags: wordpress

i have setup wishlist membership plugin and created three different membership level.

1. free
2. staff
3. gold

and every different membership successfully registration have three different redirect page.

like this way 
[image]

and wishlist member || Settings » Configuration » System Pages : "After Registration Page:" leaved it blank.
[image]
The problem is when i complete the registration process, every membership level redirect thank you page but it should go on my custom redirect for every level. but it not works.
What should i have to do? any suggestion please ?

Answer (score 2):

Your settings are correct, you need to check if maybe another plugin has some redirection override.

Also, you can go into the Wishlist Member settings >> miscellaneous and change the settings of "Allow Wishlist Member to handle login redirect" to "Yes".

Although this setting only handles the after-login redirection, in some cases this will solve a plugin conflict and force WordPress to use the Wishlist Member redirection.

Hope that helps!

Dana